# How to rewrite given two dependent types are equal in Coq

Tags: coq, dependent-type

I'm working on a proof using bit vectors from the [bbv](https://github.com/mit-plv/bbv) library which look like `word : nat -> Set`. I'm trying to prove that the most significant bit is the same if you chop off some lower-order bits:

```
Require Import bbv.Word.
Require Import Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.
Require Import Coq.Arith.Plus.

Lemma drop_msb : forall (n : nat) (x : word (S (S n))),
  wmsb x false = wmsb (wtl x) false.
```

To prove this, the following lemma seems useful:

```
Check wmsb_split2.
(*
wmsb_split2 :
  forall sz (w: word (sz + 1)) b,
    wmsb w b = if weq (split2 _ 1 w) (natToWord _ 0) then false else true.
*)
```

Now, here's my attempt at the proof:

```
Proof.
  intros n x.
  assert (Snp : S (S n) = S n + 1). {
    rewrite <- Nat.add_1_l.
    apply plus_comm.
  }
  assert (xeq : word (S (S n)) = word ((S n) + 1)). {
    rewrite Snp.
    reflexivity.
  }
  rewrite wmsb_split2. (* Error: Found no subterm matching "wmsb ?M1864 ?M1865" in the current goal. *)
```

Here is the proof state.

```
  n : nat
  x : word (S (S n))
  Snp : S (S n) = S n + 1
  xeq : word (S (S n)) = word (S n + 1)
  ============================
  wmsb x false = wmsb (wtl x) false
```

I'm confused why `wmsb_split2` can't be applied; I see `wmsb _ _` right there in the conclusion! Do I need some form of the uniqueness of identity proofs given in [EqDepFacts](https://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.Logic.EqdepFacts.html)?

I also have the extra assertions there in case I need to rewrite `x`, but I can't do that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simpler proof by computation: because `word` is defined as a list of bits indexed by its length, if you know that the length is `S (S n)`, then the first two constructors of the list are uniquely determined, and that fact is provided by the lemma `destruct_word_S`.

```
destruct_word_S :
  forall (sz : nat) (w : word (S sz)),
    exists (v : word sz) (b : bool), w = WS b v
```

In this case, that allows you to rewrite `x : word (S (S n))` twice, into some term `WS b0 (WS b1 x'')`, that enables both `wmsb` and `wtl` to compute.

To use `destruct_word_S` for rewriting, you have to destruct the two `exists` to expose the equality `w = WS b v`.

```
Lemma drop_msb : forall (n : nat) (x : word (S (S n))),
  wmsb x false = wmsb (wtl x) false.
Proof.
  intros.
  destruct (destruct_word_S x) as [x' [b0 Ex]].
  destruct (destruct_word_S x') as [x'' [b1 Ex']].
  rewrite Ex.
  rewrite Ex'. cbn.
  (* Goal: wmsb x'' b1 = wmsb x'' b1 *)
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

---

> I'm confused why wmsb_split2 can't be applied; I see wmsb _ _ right there in the conclusion!

The length of the word is an implicit argument to `wmsb`, and that's what doesn't unify here: the `wmsb_split2` lemma uses `@wmsb (sz + 1)` and your goal uses `@wmsb (S (S n))` on the left-hand side, and `@wmsb (S n)` on the right-hand side. But `sz + 1` is not convertible to `S (S n)` (i.e., they can not normalize to the same term, for any instantiation of `sz`).

When dealing with indexed types, such as `word`, which is indexed by the length, equality behaves quite unintuitively.

I find that what works well in this context is inversion principles, like `destruct_word_S`, formulated in terms of *homogeneous* equality, i.e., `=`/`eq`, where both sides have the same type.

In contrast, *heterogeneous* equality spells trouble, and that's what you are getting into when you start thinking in terms of "a `word (S sz)` is also a `word (sz + 1)`", trying to equate things of different types.

Sadly I don't know of a good way of gaining the proper intuition here, other than the less than satisfactory path of learning about dependent type theory, to treat `eq` as "just another inductive type", being aware of all the ways it does not behave like a naive idea of "equality".